# iOS SDK 5.0 iPhone Application Trouble

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, storyboard

I'm working on my first iPhone application and have stumbled upon an unknown bug in my code. The code works perfectly fine, but the problem lies when I tap a custom UIButton I've made and when it loads the next view. I have a desired buttonPressed IBAction that is called to handle what information loads on the next view controller, but the order of the function calls is wrong. I have 5 different buttonPressed functions and 3 out of the 5 are working correctly. Note I implemented them the same exact way through Storyboard and even tried re-making the non-working ones. I'd post code but the code is basic if/else statements. I'm just not sure why 3 out of the 5 ways would work and the other 2 wouldn't. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

**This is the desired order for the working 3:

viewDidLoad -> Loads main screen (initial view controller AKA ROOT, On main screen, you have 5 UIButtons to choose a category, tap a button to load to a new view controller)

categoryButtonPressed -> Sets counter (seques to new view controller)

viewDidLoad -> Loads Screen to narrow down search

(Now you have 10+ Custom Buttons to Tap on, each will be handled through a             buttonPressed IBAction function, and once button is tapped and function is called, a new view is loaded)

buttonPressed -> Sets counter (seques to new view controller)

viewDidLoad -> Loads correct information

This is the order for the non-working 2:

viewDidLoad -> Loads main screen (initial view controller AKA ROOT)
(On main screen, you have 5 UIButtons to choose a category, tap a button to load to a new view controller)

categoryButtonPressed -> Sets counter (seques to new view controller)

viewDidLoad -> Loads Screen to narrow down search
(Now you have 10+ Custom Buttons to Tap on, each will be handled through a             buttonPressed IBAction function, and once button is tapped and function is called, a new view is loaded)

viewDidLoad -> Loads blank information (blank screen)

buttonPressed -> Sets counter but is to late as the view already was loaded blank

Thoughts?**

Here is an example of the categoryButtonPressed:

-(IBAction)categoryButtonPressed:(id)sender

{

```
if([sender tag] == 1)

    counter = 1;

else if([sender tag] == 2)

    counter = 2;

.

.

.
```

}

NOTE: I have each custom button tagged for a specific item to be loaded. This function is just to set a counter so another function can load a specific file.

Comment: @LuisOscar thanks, you are right, I should have added a comment, not an answer... my bad.

Very hard to tell without more information....

Am i correct in understanding that your button press should be setting some parameter of the upcoming viewController and then transitioning to that view controller?

It seems strange that the secondary view controller should load without pressing the button, which is what it looks like above. Where do you initialize that controller in your code?

Comment: I've updated the problem, and maybe now you can get understand what I am trying to do and figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Use segues.

On your main view controller set up the segues by loading the desired information on the view controller when a specific segue is pressed.

You can follow this guide which is the way you should do it if you are using story boards

http://www.scott-sherwood.com/?p=219

**Look for the "prepareForSegue" methods, when using storyboards, modally presented views should be pre configured this way.**

On a side note, the "viewDidLoad" is usually not used to load another view, it should be used to configure that view after it has been loaded.

Comment: Well I am using modal segues. The problem I am having is that 3 out of the 5 work correctly. I have setup each the exact same way and am baffled as to why they aren't working correctly. All I need to do is somehow find a way to change the order of the function calls for the 2 non-working views.

Comment: are you using the "prepareForSegue" methods? thats what i meant by the link i gave you. when a button which will lead you to a new view is pressed. You configure that view there so that it is ready when it appears. Your problem is possibly how you use viewdidLoad, Try setting an NSLOG in the viewdidload and see when it is getting called, my bet is that its getting "loaded" before it has the info to be loaded the way you want. this is why i recomend using the appropiate segue methods. read that link.

Comment: well that is my problem, the view controller is loaded before the buttonPressed function is called, thus loading an empty screen. But why would this not work while the other 3 buttonPressed actions did?

Comment: because you should not rely on when the controller is loaded for displaying stuff, if you can ensure the view is not visible before that button has been pressed, use the "viewWillAppear" method instead. This should let the view "reconfigure" itself before it appears on the screen based on the button.

Comment: How would you explain why the order of the function calls is different though?

Comment: I can explain it to you but you have to edit your question to specify exactly what is what, I need to know the structure of the story board (rootviewcontroller conected to what), and according to you the viewdidload is inverted on the non working 2, how did you manage to make viewdidload get executed twice on the same view controller (for the first 3).

Comment: Ok I updated the problem, hopefully you can understand better what I am saying. The problem is "why are the function calls different", and how to fix this. The problem isn't in the code. The code works perfectly. The order of the buttonPress and the new view being loaded via viewDidLoad is swapped for the non-working 2 categories. Hopefully this is clear by now. Thanks.

Comment: As @LuisOscar says, you can't rely on when the controller is loaded for displaying things.  My guess, you had a race condition based on how large (and thus how long) the new view controllers were.  3 of them might be larger and thus load slower... allowing your expected and desired operation.  This is a guess though without seeing 'under the hood'

Comment: Additionally, I would say that the problem IS the code.  Just because it works 3/5 times, doesn't mean it was done the correct way.  If you break convention, or do things that are not anticipated, (like loading views in viewDidLoad), unbounded / strange things can happen.

Comment: They are all 5 the exact same size. They are basically mirror images of one another but with slight wording/text differences. This shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: @JohnnnBoyyy well from the outline of your explanation i would say that the problem is in how you are passing the information from the rootviewcontroller to the other view controller.

Comment: How do you give this information to the new viewcontroller, also you have just 1 button right? and you define which viewcontroller you want loaded using other attributes?, could you post the code for the action that the button performs, it doesn't matter if its long and meaningless, just paste it with the code formatting thing and it should be formatted nicely and easy to read.

Comment: from the root controller, all it has is 5 buttons, and each is connected to a separate view via storyboard. This is done properly and I am having no problem with that aspect. But for the information being loaded after the categoryButtonPressed, I have some logic that will load data from the selected category once the view is loaded. The problem is that this logic is executed before the categoryButtonPressed to implement the correct logic.

Comment: So you have 5 buttons or 6 (5 and a category button)?, each of the 5 buttons leads to a different view controller. IF each of the buttons could lead to only 1 possible view then preprogramming these views would be the obvious choice which means you have something else that will alter what is displayed in that view. I want to know HOW you pass this information to THAT view, if you use the prepareforsegue method, or a customized constructor on that view or something. the problem is in this step.

Comment: well the main screen has 5 buttons (categories), then a screen comes up with around 11 custom image buttons (custom class I created from regular UIButtons) for each category and each are tagged with a number, see code added above for how the counter is set, and finally the view loads the text information depending on the counter that was set for the given category.

Comment: Ok i think i got it, your main controller has 5 buttons, you push one and 10 more buttons appear. (this works ok for all your 5 initial buttons). if you push one button in this new screen only the ones coming from the first 3 will show the correct information on the THIRD view controller. right? in your story board are they connected as, 1 to 5 and each of this 5 connects to another one which is the same for all 5 on the same 10 buttons? or does each button of the 5 views goes to their on view controller?. Do not rely on viewdidload, use viewWillAppear instead.

Comment: view 1: main screen (5 buttons) view 2: category chosen (10-11 buttons) view 3: information display screen , how will viewWillAppear solve the problem I am having? I can't say this enough, that the viewDidLoad is not the problem, and the problem lies with an odd order in my 2 non-working buttonPressed functions. viewDidLoad doesn't have any relation to the 2 functions in any way.

Comment: view will appear will ensure that your new configuration is always loaded on the third view regardless of if the view has already been loeaded or not. Because your buttonpress belongs to the second view, by the time the third view "WIll appear" you can be sure that you have already pressed the button. so the order wont matter. have you tried pressing the buttons in a different order? like on the first view, press 1 of the non working button first, and on the second another button. the correct info should display on the third because the third has not been loaded at all.

Comment: If it however still doesnt display the correct information then, ensure that from the second to the third viewcontroller. you are properly creating a new Viewcontroller EACH TIME otherwise you cannot rely on the view did load. (and dont forget that the old view controller must be destroyed when the third view dissapears)

Comment: I've tried implementing viewWillAppear as you mentioned, and I get the same problem. I've tried everything to my knowledge and surfed the entire internet and still stuck with the same issue. Thank you for all of your help.

Comment: sorry i cant be of more help, if the project is not secret or anything you can always add a link to a zip file or git hub from it and i can take a look. Honestly i think the problem is very easy to solve.

Comment: I know it is. It has to be something simple, but it's a project that is almost ready for the app store (minus this glitch), otherwise I would have sent it to you hours ago.